# Horizontal scroll with c#

Tags: c#, mousemove, user32

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains helpful information on how to use the mouse_event function located in user32.dll

Based on that link I know that I could scroll by doing something like:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);


        public void Scroll(){
              // this will cause a vertical scroll
              mouse_event(0x0800, 0, 0, 500, 0);
        }

        public void Click(){
              // this will cause a left mouse click
              mouse_event(0x0002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
              Thread.Sleep(1);
              mouse_event(0x0004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        // etc...
```

anyways if  you look at that link, it does not contain the int value for MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL. I will like to be able to use the horizontal scroll. How can I use the move_event to create a horizontal wheel movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL` is 0x1000. So for example:

```
// this will cause a horizontal scroll to the right
mouse_event(0x1000, 0, 0, 200, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the same link you provided, you would see that:

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

If you look at the documentation for SendInput, you see that you can send an array of [INPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures. If you look at the documentation for INPUT, you see that you can send keyboard (KEYBDINPUT) or mouse inputs (MOUSEINPUT).

Finally, the documentation for [MOUSEINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that you can use **MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL**.

> Windows Vista: If dwFlags contains MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL, then dwData specifies the amount of wheel movement. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated to the right; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated to the left.

So, you should use `SendInput`. It's a little more complicated, but you can use it to scroll horizontally. You can check the [PInvoke page for SendInput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/sendinput.html) to get an example.

Comment: Ove thanks for the help. I can see that the sendInput method has a lot more functionality. The only method that I was missing was the hwheel one. should I use the sendInput instead and migrate all the mouse gestures that I had to that one?

Comment: I would say it depends on how much work you need to do. If I were you I would switch to SendInput because it's better not to use superseded functions. Maybe in some future version of Windows, mouse_event won't even work anymore. Also, take a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/4f705f47-af2a-4491-b241-ee38ca1aa3a6/)

Comment: I'll try to change it if it is to much trouble then I leave it as is. thanks for the help again.